# Constraint layout not shown

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbChat"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_peer_chat_message" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_chat_edit_text"
        android:maxLines="6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendContainer"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgAttach" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cancelAudio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendContainer"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDialog">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAudioRecordDuration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="0:0"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAudioRecordCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Swipe to cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendContainer"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnMic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAttach"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_add" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/attachmentsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDialog">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnShareLocation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgCaptureImage"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCaptureImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnShareLocation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgPickImage"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnShareLocation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnShareLocation"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_red_700_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPickImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgCaptureImage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imgCancel"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgCaptureImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgCaptureImage"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_landscape_teal_a700_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPickImage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPickImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgPickImage"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

it is found in a library and then I publish my library and try to use the fragment that use this layout in my app

what happen that the fragment appear but with no buttons

can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

**EDIT**
This is the layout of the activity that should contains the previous Fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<include
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    layout="@layout/item_actionbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_seperator_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seperator" />
```

**EDIT2**

This is that layout that should be appear , but it does not appear like this, it appear without the add and audio buttons

[image]

Comment: read how to design in constraint layout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: it is working in the library project, but it does not work when I use the library project inside my app, did you even read my question ?

Comment: What is your parent layout?

Comment: my parent layout of the activity that contains this fragment is Relative Layout

Comment: Then you should use _android:layout_below="+id/YourViewId"_

Comment: @Piyush please check my question edit

Comment: Change _app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDialog"_ to _app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvDialog"_. Also give static some static height instead of _0dp_

Comment: @Piyush ok will try and get back to you

Comment: @Piyush I tried it but still it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184082/discussion-between-piyush-and-amira-elsayed-ismail).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from `ConstraintLayout` - `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: no it meant to be invisible to hide it and show it only when user press a button